# Split Data Table by Column Count

Tags: c#, datatable, split

How would I split up a DataTable that has dynamic column count and names

Ideally I'd like a method signature like

```
List<DataTable> SplitColumnOnColumn(DataTable table, int count)
```

| columnFirst | columnSecond | columnThird | columnFourth | columnFifth |
|   row1val1     |   row1val2            |   row1val3      |   row1val4          |  row1val5      |
|   row2val1      |   row2val2            |   row2val3       |   row2val4          |  row2val5      |
|   row3val1     |   row3val2             |   row3val3      |   row3val4          |  row3val5      |

Given the above table

```
SplitColumnOnColumn(myTable, 3)
```

Which would produce

| columnFirst | columnSecond | columnThird |
|   row1val1     |   row1val2            |   row1val3      |
|   row2val1      |   row2val2            |   row2val3       |
|   row3val1     |   row3val2             |   row3val3      |

| columnFourth | columnFifth |
|   row1val4          |  row1val5      |
|   row2val4          |  row2val5      |
|   row3val4          |  row3val5      |

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `DataTable` doesn't provide this feature out-of-the-box, you'll have to create it yourself.

My suggestion would be to clone your `DataTable`, then Remove the columns from each table that you don't want.

*Modifying the example below into a usable function is left as an excursive to the reader.*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] sourceData = {0,0,0,0,0};
        DataTable source = new DataTable();
        source.Columns.Add("ColOne");
        source.Columns.Add("ColTwo");
        source.Columns.Add("ColThree");
        source.Columns.Add("ColFour");
        source.Columns.Add("ColFive");

        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 5; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < source.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
            {
                sourceData[colIndex] = rowIndex * colIndex;
            }
            source.Rows.Add(sourceData);
        }

        DataTable target = new DataTable();
        target = source.Clone();

        Console.WriteLine("Before split");
        Console.Write("Source -> ");
        foreach (DataColumn col in source.Columns) { 
            Console.Write(col.ColumnName + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Target -> ");
        foreach (DataColumn col in target.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write(col.ColumnName + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        target.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
        target.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
        target.Columns.RemoveAt(0);

        source.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
        source.Columns.RemoveAt(3);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("After split");
        Console.Write("Source -> ");
        foreach (DataColumn col in source.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write(col.ColumnName + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Target -> ");
        foreach (DataColumn col in target.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write(col.ColumnName + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        if (Debugger.IsAttached) {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ANY KEY TO EXIT");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After Dan-o's suggestions of how to tackle this I came up with this.

```
public List<DataTable> SplitOnColumnCount(DataTable inputTable, int columnCount)
    {
        if (inputTable == null || columnCount < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var tableList = new List<DataTable>();
        var grouping = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((inputTable.Columns.Count) / ((double)columnCount)));
        var columnNames = inputTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(_ => _.ColumnName).ToArray();

        for (var i = 1; i <= grouping; i++)
        {
            var columnsThisTime = columnNames.Skip((i - 1) * columnCount).Take(columnCount).ToArray();
            var newTable = inputTable.Copy();
            var removingColumns = columnNames.Where(_ => columnsThisTime.All(keep => keep != _));
            foreach (var columnName in removingColumns)
            {
                newTable.Columns.Remove(columnName);
            }
            newTable.AcceptChanges();
            tableList.Add(newTable);
        }

        return tableList;
    }
```

Comment: Why did you choose to add rows one at a time instead of cloning the table?